# Codeigniter save ajax response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I want to **save the ajax response** I get into my database. The problem is that my ajax function doesn't allow my to put a insert query. When I Insert the insert query, my response doesn't work anymore and vice versa.

**where ajax file is**

```
public function submit()    {

$data = array(
'user_id' => '1',
'swipedpicture' => $this->input->post()
);
$this->db->insert('tbl_results', $data);
print json_encode($data);
}
```

**Ajax Jquery**

```
var pic = $(this).find('input[name="inputcountry"]').attr('value');
    jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: window.location.origin +"/swipr/index.php/preferences/submit",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {swipedpic: pic},
    success: function(res) {
    if (res) {
    console.log(res.swipedpicture);
    }

  }
  });
```

Comment: `$this->input->post('swipedpic')`

Comment: No it still doesn't work.. Like I said, from the minute I add more code, even the $this->db->insert('tbl_results', $data), I don't get my ajax response anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript is setting a data element for posting that the submit function is not using.

The submit function should look like this.

```
$data = array(
        'user_id' => '1',
        'swipedpicture' => $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('swipedpicture'))
    );
    $this->db->insert('tbl_results', $data);
    $response_array['status'] = 'success';

    echo json_encode($response_array);
```

The javascript should look more like this. I used an form id of form1 and a form element of swipedpicture.

```
$('#form1').submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'example_answer_submit',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: $('#form1').serialize(),
                    success: function (msg) {
                        if (!msg) {
                        console.log('error');
                    } else {
                        console.log('success');
                    }
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
```

The form I used.

```
<h1 class="page-header text-center">Test Form</h1>
                    <form id="form1" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Swiped Picture</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="swipedpicture" name="swipedpicture" placeholder="Pic" value="">
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                                <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                                <?php echo $result; ?>  
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Comment: It doen't work. When I add this code I don't get my ajax response anymore.. And it doesn't save to my table

Comment: Can you see the posted values in the console?

Also, is the pic field a file field?

Comment: If I insert your code, it doen't log teh response anymore. The pic is just a value form an hidden input field.

Comment: I'm putting together an example and testing it. Will take me just a couple of minutes.

Comment: The data: $('#form1').serialize() and swipedpicture' => $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('swipedpicture')) worked for me, thank you